# How to install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-line, wine, software-update

I am not able to find Wine in software center of Ubuntu. How can I install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 (64 BIT)?

Answer (score 4):

To install Wine version 5.0 in Ubuntu 20.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install wine wine64 winetricks
```

The wine package provides essential wrappers and convenience tools for the standard Wine components.

That's all you need to install Wine version 5.0 in Ubuntu 20.04 unless you also want to install 32-bit programs with Wine, in which case you also need to install the wine32 package with `sudo apt install wine32`.

Comment: in my Ubuntu 20.04 machine with `install wine` I got by default the 32 bits version..

Answer (score 3):

> How can I install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 (64 BIT)?

You need to run the following commands:

> 1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
> 2. `wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -`
> 3. `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'`
> 4. `sudo apt update`
> 5. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Source: [Installing WineHQ packages](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)